# Cabal - sharing datatypes

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a top level file called `Datatypes.hs`. It's exposed in my cabal file.

```
library
    exposed-modules: Application
                     Foundation
                     Import
                     Settings
                     Settings.Development
                     Datatypes
                     Handler.Advise
```

I'd like to use `Datatypes` in my test code. Here's what I have tried

test-suite test
    type:              exitcode-stdio-1.0
    main-is:           tests/testclient.hs
    hs-source-dirs:    .,tests
    ghc-options:       -Wall

```
build-depends: base
             , Datatypes
             , conduit == 0.5.2.7
             , attoparsec-conduit == 0.5.0.2
             , transformers == 0.3.0.0
             , resourcet == 0.4.0.2
             , http-conduit                  >= 1.5        && < 1.7
             , utf8-string == 0.3.7
             , aeson == 0.6.0.2
```

I still get complaints about datatypes in testclient.hs not being defined. Is what I am doing possible? For now I will just paste in my data types into testclient.hs, but I'd like to just be able to refer to `Datatypes.hs`

Comment: `Datatypes` isn't a package, so it doesn't belong in the build-depends. I don't know the test-suite stuff, so it could either need to have its directory listed in the hs-source-dirs, or itself be listed in the other-modules field (probably the latter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't list individual modules in the `build-depends` field - use the name of your package instead. For an example, look at the [`.cabal` file for `unordered-containers`](https://github.com/tibbe/unordered-containers/blob/master/unordered-containers.cabal):

```
test-suite strictness-properties
  hs-source-dirs: tests
  main-is: Strictness.hs
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0

  build-depends:
    base,
    [...]
    unordered-containers
```